# How to perform exponentiation using boost multiprecision and boost math?

Tags: c++, boost, floating-accuracy

I am running a biased Monte Carlo simulation, and I need to process the energies being reported. I essentially have to compute `exp(-beta*energy)`, where energy is a negative number and beta can be around 100. If `energy = 90`, `std::exp` starts outputting `inf`.
This is a test run:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/expm1.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
   // using namespace boost::multiprecision;

    double u = std::exp (900.0);

   boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50 v = 2.71;

   // loop for e^900
   for(unsigned i = 1; i < 901; ++i){
      v *= 2.71;
   }
   
   boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50 x = boost::math::expm1 (900.0);

   std::cout << "u = " << u << std::endl; 
   std::cout << "v = " << v << std::endl; 
   std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;  

   return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
u = inf
v = 1.27447e+390
x = inf
```

My question is, how do i perform this exponentiation, and get the answer like in `v`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @user1095108. How do you mean though? Do you have any recommendations for how I must proceed?

Comment: Perhaps try `boost::math::expm1<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50>(900)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `exp`! **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/1sTxosbec)**

```
boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50 x = 900.0;
std::cout << "v = " << exp(x) << std::endl;
```

Prints

```
v = 7.32881e+390
```

The difference between `exp(900.0)` and `exp(x)` is that `900.0` is of type `double` and `x` is `cpp_dec_float_50`.

ADL finds the correct overload for `exp` in the associated namespace.